# Can't retrieve session variable from PHP script

Tags: php, sql, ajax, sql-update, session-variables

I have an ajax posting of a form so that I can return values from PHP exactly as it shows here: https://jonsuh.com/blog/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return/ .
There's a slight difference though, my response.php script is like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

$email = $_SESSION['email'];

?>

<?php    
if (is_ajax()) {
    if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { 
        $action = $_POST["action"];
        switch($action) { 
        case "test": test_function(); break;
        }
    }
}

function is_ajax() {
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&   strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test_function(){
    $return = $_POST;
    $x = $return["Profile"];

    define('DB_NAME', 'STUDENTS');
    define('DB_USER', 'STUDENTS');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'PASSWORD');
    define('DB_HOST','HOST');

    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);       
    $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link); 

    $sql = "UPDATE  `STUDENTS`.`Students` SET  `Fbprofile` =  '$x' WHERE  `Students`.`StudEmail` = '$email'  ";

    $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
    echo json_encode($return);
}
?>
```

As you can see, the only difference is that I'm updating an SQL database. The problem is that I want to update the Fbprofile column where StudEmail equals the email session variable. This session variable works perfectly in all other pages, but I can't seem to retrieve it in my response.php. What actually happens is that the SQL update works but only updates all rows that have no email value in them, so I'm guessing it's not reading the $email variable.
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What does `var_dump($_SESSION)` show? Is this script in the same subdomain and folder as all the other scripts? Why are you "guessing" that it's the `$email` variable instead of actively debugging it?

Comment: We really shouldn't help you to debug your own code ...

Comment: it's just you need to declarre 'global $email' to use the external variable inside the function

Comment: Instead of global, why not pass it in the function argument? test_function($email) ? Also test_function() could work with $_SESSION directly (bad idea but you _could_)

Answer (score 4):

It's a variable scope problem. You set `$email` outside of `test_function`, so it's not visible inside the function. If you had error reporting enabled, you would have seen a notice about the undefined variable.

You should pass it as an argument to the function:

```
    case "test": test_function($email); break;
```

...

```
function test_function($email) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I really appreciate the help, now it works. I've only been programming for less than two months now. 

I have to say I am rather disappointed by some of the comments on stack overflow, there is a tendency to make fun of people who clearly are just starting to approach this new world, it's quite pettish and pretty useless, since it is due to comments like yours (Barman) rather than those others that  allows people like myself to improve.

Thanks again,

G.R.

Comment: When many of us came here, we thought it was a place for experienced programmers to help each other with difficult problems. Unfortunately, it ends up being mostly giving basic programming lessons to newbies, and that can be very frusatrating.